# How to decrease file size of exported video from After effect CC 2015 with RGB+ALPHA option?

Tags: animation, video, after-effects

I have done Lowest video size of RBG+ALPHA in after effect CS with FLV-Quick time option but in after effect CC 2016 there is not any option can you help me to resolve this please ?

Comment: Is it a programming question?

Comment: Nop it is question regarding animation video

Answer (score 0):

FLV is **not available anymore** in After Effects, but it is in *Adobe Media Encoder*.

You can export your composition directly from After Effects to Media Encoder and then choose FLV (follow [this tutorial](https://helpx.adobe.com/after-effects/how-to/ame-export-compositions-cc.html) to get more instructions), this is a clean workflow?

Otherwise, you can make your render in PNG and then compress in FLV which is much more longer but you still have a clean version if you don't want to recalculate the composition for another render. And you will probably use Media Encoder so you can export your composition